# Angular 2 *ngFor Error

Tags: angular

I am getting this error
"find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

here is my code:

```
<tbody>

                <tr *ngFor='let tab of tabs'>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list">
                            <li><a href="#" class="anchorLink"><i class="icon-home scolor"></i><font color="white">{{tab.TabName}}</font></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>
```

navMenu.copnent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavMenuService } from './navMenu.service';
import { InavMenuTabs } from './navMenu';

@Component({
selector: 'nav-menu',
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: 'navMenu.component.html'

})

export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {

tabs: InavMenuTabs[];
errorMessage: string;
constructor(private _navMenuService: NavMenuService) {

}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this._navMenuService.getTabs(1, 'XXXX')
        .subscribe(tabs => this.tabs = tabs,      
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);



}
}
```

navMenu.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { InavMenuTabs } from './navMenu';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()

export class NavMenuService {

private _fileUploadAPI = 'http://localhost:50180/API/FileUpload/GetTabs/';
constructor(private _http: Http) {

}

getTabs(LinkID: number, PSNL_UID: string): Observable<InavMenuTabs[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._fileUploadAPI + LinkID.toString() + '/' + PSNL_UID)
        .map((response: Response) => <InavMenuTabs[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);


}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
}
}
```

navMenu.ts

```
export interface InavMenuTabs {

LinkTabID: number;
TabName: string;
}
```

Comment: `.subscribe(tabs => this.tabs = tabs,` does not return an array as you expect, but something else.

Comment: tabs is an array see code : tabs: InavMenuTabs[];  . I am new to angular and not sure what am I missing

Comment: You have just typed it as a array, doesn't mean that it's an array. You could type it as anything you want, doesn't matter during runtime :)

Comment: then how to fix the issue :)

Comment: you want to might to check how the data looks like which is coming, e.g change your subscription to: `.subscribe(data => { console.log(data)}) ` so you get to see what kind of data is actually arriving :)

Comment: already did :)  this._navMenuService.getTabs(1, 'XXXX')
        .subscribe(tabs => {
          console.log(tabs);
          this.tabs = tabs;
        },      
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);                                        it shows [object Object]. and from navenu.service i see I get:
All{"result":[{"LinkTabID":1,"TabName":"Upload File"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking at your comments, that explains it. Your incoming data is not an Array, but an object named `result`, so you have to get the content from that object and store it in your array.

When you mapped your incoming data it showed:

```
{"result":[{"LinkTabID":1,"TabName":"Upload File"}]}
```

which is an object containing an array. So you have to get that array from your object.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._navMenuService.getTabs(1, 'XXXX')
        .subscribe(
           data => {
             this.tabs = data.result
           });
}
```

Comment: when I put this                                                                                                             ngOnInit(): void {
        this._navMenuService.getTabs(1, 'ciiw')
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tabs = data
                this.tabs = JSON.parse(this.tabs.result) //error in .result
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////JSON.parse(this.tabs.result) cause an error this.tabs.result

Comment: Just copy the above code exactly the way I have written, it should work, your current code is a mishmash of your old code as well.

Comment: sorry I got it, when I do this I get another exception:Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2838
core.umd.js:2843 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2843

Comment: Well now, messed up a bit myself, sorry for that. Updated my answer, NOW it should work like I have written in answer :)

Comment: still get an error from data.result . the error "result property does not exists on InavMenuTabs[]"

Comment: updated my answer again, look at it and try accordingly - strip away a little from the http method as well, if that would help

Comment: i changed my navMenu.service without any issues, however, navMenu.componenet.ts is failing i get four errors(it does not  like the declaration tabs;) :Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS7008 Member 'tabs' implicitly has an 'any' type. TypeScript Virtual Projects 
Error TS2304 Cannot find name 'tabs'. TypeScript Virtual 
Error TS7008 Build:Member 'tabs' implicitly has an 'any' type.  
Error TS2304 Build:Cannot find name 'tabs'.

Comment: :D Uhmm, well strange to complain about type `any`, but oh well... try either `tabs: any;` or do you have an "class" for tabs, not interface? if you have class, type it as `tabs: YourTabsClass[]` Do you actually use the Interface? I mean, usually one doesn't need it :)

Comment: This is how I learned when I went through angular tutorial :). an interface just away to make it easy to code so you just do tabs.something and so on it wont accept tabs; or tabs:any; so I just put it as tabs:  tabs: InavMenuTabs[];. anyways i changed it to export class. InavMenuTabs {

    LinkTabID: number;
    TabName: string;

} and still have errors Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2304 Cannot find name 'tabs'. 
Error TS2304 Build:Cannot find name 'tabs'.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker. Tabs are defined in your project, so it shouldn't be a problem, that's why I wonder why it says that tabs can not be found. The code I provided in my answer is the solution to your question, tested it myself now. Now there must be some error somewhere... hard to say since I don't have your code.

Comment: And BTW, if you changed your interface to a class, you need to modify it and put a constructor in it.

Comment: OMG, I found the issue and all is good even with  tabs: InavMenuTabs[];. I was misspelling in my service code. Thank you verrry much

Comment: Okay, good. That's what I thought, typing or casting your incoming data has no effect, as TS is a superset of JS, where there is no types. So even if you have typed your incoming data as a dog, it doesn't matter during runtime. Your compiler will complain, but your code would run as expected :) But you still had to subscribe like so: `this.tabs = data.result`? If so, would you kindly accept my answer, as that would be exactly the solution to your question :)

Comment: I just accepted, I did not know how to do that because I am knew to typescript. Took the tour and was able to do it :)